# PHP DOM DomText vs DomElement treatment of entities

Tags: php, xml, dom, entities

Why is there a difference in treatment of entities when using DomElement versus DomText?

example code:

```
$text = 'this&that or this&amp; that';
$document = new \DOMDocument;

$p1 = $document->createElement('p', $text);
// versus
$p2 = $document->createElement('p');
$p2->appendChild($document->createTextNode($text));

var_dump($p1->nodeValue); // thisthat
var_dump($p2->nodeValue); // this&that or this&amp;that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the difference is that the `createElement` does not accept (accents) and illegal characters in markup and if so, will ignore this kind of character

Comment: But why this different in treatment? Is this dom specified?

Comment: has no documentation, the createElement does not treat the input value, in this case you have to do this manually, it's been createTextNode treatment because the specifications of the xml